# Why must we use the method of image to calculate the surface charge density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, method-of-images

A point charge $Q$ is brought to a position a distance $d$ away from an infinite plane conductor held at zero potential, now calculate the surface-charge density induced on the plane.

The book always writes we use the method of image, so the surface charge density,$ \rho_s$, is $$ \epsilon_0 \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0 4 \pi}\left[\frac{z+d}{(x^2+y^2+(z+d)^2)^{3/2}}+\frac{z-d}{(x^2+y^2+(z-d)^2)^{3/2}}\right]$$

But in my opinion, I know the $$E=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0 4 \pi d^2 }= \frac{\rho_s 4 \pi d^2}{\epsilon_0 4 \pi d^2 },$$so $$ \rho_s =\epsilon_0 E= \epsilon_0 \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0 4 \pi d^2 }$$

Now obviously my and the book's answers are different, so I want to ask why is my answer wrong? Which part of the my calculation or thinking is wrong? Why must we use the method of image to calculate the surface charge density?

Comment: What is $d$? What is $R$? Where is the point charge and where is the plane? How do you know $E$ is given by that expression? Please edit your question to include these details, and double check your equations.

Comment: @Puk A point charge $Q$ is brought to a position a distance $d$ away from an infinite plane conductor held at zero potential,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making two mistakes:

1. In your approach you are missing out that the field produced by the charge not only depends on $d$, but on the x and y position along the plate as well.
2. The charge induces a non-zero charge distribution in the conductor, which in turn creates its own electric field. This is what you are taking into account when using the image charge.

Comment: so if the question didn’t tell me the coordination,i can ignore the x,y,z axis when i am calculating the field?

Comment: thankyou now i know why and when should we use the method of image